# Does Kotlin support passng a custom function as a variable in another function?

Tags: kotlin, function-pointers

I have a class I need to pass custom functions to an alert dialog, in effect creating a custom callback function

Here's some pseudo code.

```
fun someFunction(v: View) {
  ...
  ShowPopup(name, "Title", {YesAction(v, "Test for yes action")},{NoAction(v, "Test for no action")})
  ...
}

fun NoAction (v: View, msg: String) {
  SendMessage( v, msg)
  SomeCancelationFunction() 
}

fun YesAction (v: View, msg: String) {
  SendMessage(v, msg) 
  SomeYesAction()
}

fun SendMessage(v: View, msg: String) {
    var snack = Snackbar.make(v, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    snack.show()
}

fun ShowPopup(msg: String,
      title: String,
      cbFuncYes: () - > Unit,
      cbFuncNo: () - > Unit
) {
  val dlgBldr = AlertDialog.Builder(this @MainActivity)
  dlgBldr.setPositiveButton("YES", {_,_ -> ::cbFuncYes()})
  dlgBldr.setNegativeButton("No", {_,_ -> ::cbFuncNo()})
  dlgBldr.setTitle(title)
  dlgBldr.setMessage(msg)
  val dlgShow: AlertDialog = builder.create()
  dlgShow.show()
}
```

My goal is to be able to call the `ShowPopup()` function handing it some functions as variables to be used in the set pos/neg actions for the alert dialog.

Comment: Sure.  What do you think `cbFuncYes` and `cbFuncNo` are in the first place?  They're functions passed around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One way:**

You coud change the type of `cbFuncYes` and `cbFuncNo` to `(DialogInterface, Int) -> Unit` and pass them like this

```
val dlgBldr = AlertDialog.Builder(this @MainActivity)
dlgBldr.setPositiveButton("YES", ::cbFuncYes)
dlgBldr.setNegativeButton("No", ::cbFuncNo)
```

`::cbFuncYes` and `::cbFuncNo` are called function references.

**Another way:**

You invoke those passed lambdas inside the lambdas with the signature that `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton` expect like this:

```
val dlgBldr = AlertDialog.Builder(this @MainActivity)
dlgBldr.setPositiveButton("YES", {_,_ -> cbFuncYes()})
dlgBldr.setNegativeButton("No", {_,_ -> cbFuncNo()})
```

**Note:** Function names start lower-case in Kotlin.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! I wound up using the alternate method you supplied. When I tried changing the lambdas in the function adding the `(DialogInterface, Int) -> Unit` I would get an error in the callback function since it was using a `(View, String)`. Thanks again! I also was able to refactor all the functions. Cheers!